# Vimeo player pause another video when you play any video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have 2 Vimeo players in my page when I play the first video then play second video first one gets paused.

```
var vid1=new Vimeo.Player($('.one'));
var vid2=new Vimeo.Player($('.two'));
$('.btnonePlay').on('click',function(){
    vid1.play();
})
$('.btnonePause').on('click',function(){
    vid1.pause();
})
$('.btntwoPlay').on('click',function(){
    vid2.play();
})
$('.btntwoPause').on('click',function(){
    vid2.pause();
})
```

Steps on how to reproduce the issue:

1. Click on play video one
2. Click on play video two

Player one will pause when the *'play video two'* button is clicked.

## [Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sx4youg/1/).

The entire code is also in the snippet below.

```js
var vid1 = new Vimeo.Player($('.one'));
var vid2 = new Vimeo.Player($('.two'));
$('.btnonePlay').on('click', function() {
  vid1.play();
})
$('.btnonePause').on('click', function() {
  vid1.pause();
})
$('.btntwoPlay').on('click', function() {
  vid2.play();
})
$('.btntwoPause').on('click', function() {
  vid2.pause();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/286183716" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/286183716">Annihilation Song | Rubblebucket (Official Music Video)</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/amandabonaiuto">Amanda Bonaiuto</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
</div>
<button class="btnonePlay"> Play video one</button>
<button class="btnonePause"> Pause video one</button>

<div class="two">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/286183716" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/286183716">Annihilation Song | Rubblebucket (Official Music Video)</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/amandabonaiuto">Amanda Bonaiuto</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
</div>
<button class="btntwoPlay"> Play video two</button>
<button class="btntwoPause"> Pause video two</button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default on our Vimeo videos we enable `autopause`. Autopause is when one video automatically pauses when another starts playing. Most people do not want two videos playing at the same time.

However, if you do want that you can turn off autopause by using the embed parameter attached to the url `?autopause=0`. I have adjusted your jsfiddle to work accordingly. [Working JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/rebeccas/3sx4youg/4/)

You can learn more about the available embed parameters from our [API readme](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#embed-options) or this [help article](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters).